# Gmail: automatic reply without "+canned.response" in from address

Tags: gmail

I have setup some automatic responses in gmail through templates (setup a filter that sends that templated e-mail as an answer).

The problem is, that the e-mail isn't sent from `mynormal.address@mydomain.com` but from `mynormal.address+canned.response@mydomain.com`

Can I change that, so that it is sent from my regular e-mail address?